# How can I get the reference to TDSServerClass in TDSServerClass.OnCreateInstance event handler?

Tags: delphi, dynamic, rtti, datasnap

I'm using Datasnap to build a middleware, and it is business logic independent. To widely support different client apps, I encapsulate business logic into multiple subclasses of TDataModule, and expose them to client as REST api. Thus the number of subclasses and the class types are dynamically changing, and loaded as plugin.

According to Delphi XE's design pattern, I need to create one TDSServer instance as a "server", and multiple TDSServerClass instances, worked like adapters, each to serve one of my TDataModule subclasses.

The chain of classes are:
One TDSServer -> Multiple TDSServerClass(es) -> my TDataModule subclasses

My problem is to find the correspondence of TDSServerClass instances and my TDataModule subclasses in TDSServerClass.OnCreateInstance event handler.

To setup this chain and keep the correspondence, if I have 10 subclasses, for example:

1. I created 1(one) TDSServer instance, and then created **10 TDSServerClass instances**, each instance to serve one TDataModule subclass (I have stored the ID of the subclass in TDSServerClass.Tag property.
2. I created 10 pools for every subclasses on middleware startup, in each pool there are 10 instances of the subclass (there are totally 100 instances in all the pools).
3. I set TDSServerClass instances' event handler of "OnGetClass", "OnCreateInstance", "OnDestroyInstance" to my procedures to control the creation of my TDataModule subclass.
4. In the OnCreateInstance event handler (when an REST api is called by
   client), I want to pick up an instance from the opposite subclass instance
   pool.

**My problem is I can't keep the TDSServerClass->my subclass correspondence.**

**When middleware startup**, the creation of TDSServerClass instances like below:

```
FServerClasses[Len].OnGetClass := DSServerClassGetClass;
FServerClasses[Len].Tag := Len;
FServerClasses[Len].OnCreateInstance := DSServerClass1CreateInstance;
FServerClasses[Len].OnDestroyInstance := DSServerClass1DestroyInstance;
```

**When Datasnap server startup**, it trigger the the OnGetClass event, it worked well, I can find the correspondence by event handler parameter like below:

```
procedure TMainServerContainer.DSServerClassGetClass(
  DSServerClass: TDSServerClass; var PersistentClass: TPersistentClass);
begin
  PersistentClass := FindClass(FServerPersistentClasses[DSServerClass.Tag]);
end;
```

**When client app calls a REST api**, the TDSServerClass triggered OnCreateInstance event to let me pick up a subclass instance from the pool. But in the OnCreateInstance and OnDestroyInstance event handler, I can't make it work.

The event handler prototype of OnCreateInstance, for example, is like:

```
DSServerClassCreateInstance(
DSCreateInstanceEventObject: TDSCreateInstanceEventObject);
```

I've done some research on TDSCreateInstanceEventObject, but didn't find any reference to TDSServerClass who triggered the event.

Please help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nope. Instead it's my turn to create a instance of subclass and assign to ServerClassInstance property, to override the default creation handled by Datasnap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

OK, let us see if I get it now. You have 10 instances of TDSServerClass, right? And you need to find which of those 10 called the function.

The answer I would adopt would be to have 10 different DSServerClassxCreateInstance implementations and 10 different DSServerClassxDestroyInstance implementations, one for each TDataModule, a bit like this:

```
FServerClasses[3].OnCreateInstance := DSServerClass3CreateInstance;
```

It may look a bit cumbersome, and depending on your implementation you may be able to use generics to neaten things up, but it is simple and effective.

Here is an idea on how to use generics if all you really want is the TDataModule entry:

```
.....

function DSServerClassCreateInstance< T : TDataModule > : TDServerInstance;

....

FServerClasses[3].OnCreateInstance := DSServerClassCreateInstance< MyDataModule3 >;
```

Comment: Thank you, Dsm. I didn't make it clear, it's my problem. I've modified the question. Thank you again!

Comment: I have modified my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you very much, I've solved my problem based on your idea, I create a subclass of TDSServerClass and saved the classname of TDataModule class in it. Thank you for your advise, it's very helpful.